# how to enable mysql port in my online website?

Tags: mysql

For accessing my online database from local...please help me how to enable port in online , It is working when i enable mysql port in my system in FIREWALL my system mysql database is accessible for all systems in my LAN connection.

But now i want to access my online database from my system for that one i need to

> enable my website mysql port

how to access

> INTERNET FIREWALL OF MY WEBSITE

please help me , how to enable?

Answer (score 1):

please check you hosting account in that may be you will get remote sql option

as your website is coming from `yahoo server`. please check your hosting account

Answer (score 0):

Please give more details, wich server are you using Apache, IIS?

Are both the web server and mysql on the same computer?

Do you have any firewall enabled?

Are you trying to connect from a script to mysql?

Mysql default port is 3306

Have a look here, there are some sample connection strings

[MySql Connection Strings](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql)

Comment: which details you want? my website address is `www.siaedugroup.com` the domain is from yahoo server.

i want to enable online MYSQL port not in a local.